# TextInputFile, TextOutputFile (with username, pass in a login system)

Tags: java, authentication, io

```
    int menuoptions;
    String userinput;
    String usercheck="";
    String username="user";
    String password;
    int intCounter=0;

    con.println("TYPING GAME\n");
    con.println("1. Sign in");
    con.println("2. Create a new account");
    menuoptions = con.readInt();
    con.clear();

    if(menuoptions==1){
        while(!username.equals(usercheck) && intCounter==0){
            con.println("Please type in your username.");
            userinput = con.readLine();
            con.clear();
            TextInputFile infile = new TextInputFile("logins.txt");
            while(infile.eof() == false && intCounter==0){
                usercheck=infile.readLine();
                infile.readLine();
                    if(username.equals(usercheck)){
                    intCounter=intCounter+1;
                    }
            }

            if(!userinput.equals(usercheck) && intCounter==0){
                con.println("No such username.");
                pause(2000);
                con.clear();
            }       
            else if(userinput.equals(usercheck)){
                intCounter = intCounter+1;
            }
        }

        con.println("What is your password?");

    }

    if(menuoptions==2){
        con.println("What will be your username?");
        username = con.readLine();
        con.clear();
        con.println("What will be your password?");
        password = con.readLine();
        con.clear();
        TextOutputFile outfile = new TextOutputFile("logins.txt", true);
        outfile.println(username);
        outfile.println(password);
    }

}
public static void pause (int intMS){
    try{Thread.sleep(intMS);
}catch(InterruptedException y){}}
```

In logins.txt, i have 'voidturbulence' in one line, and in the next line, i have '80'.
when i type in 'voidturbulence', it jumps to 'no username found', when it should be asking for the password.

However, if userinput (voidturbulence) is equal to usercheck (the first line [voidturbulence]), then shouldn't it break out of the loop and ask me for the password?

Comment: if you are using any IDE, debug it

Answer (score 0):

**A.** The code

```
usercheck=infile.readLine();
infile.readLine();
```

looks suspicious to me. You probably have a blank line, a line with the user name, and some other text in the file read by `infile`. Thus, `usercheck` probably never receives the user name you target. (You skip every second line from `infile`.)

**B.** instead of

```
infile.eof() == false
```

use

```
!infile.eof ()
```

for better readability.
Otherwise,

```
(((infile.eof() == false) == true) == true)
```

would be considered more readable, right?

**C.** instead of

```
if (menuoptions == 1)
{
}
if (menuoptions == 2)
{
}
```

use

```
if (menuoptions == 1)
{
}
else if (menuoptions == 2)
{
}
```

since `menuoptions` cannot equal 2 when you just found it was equal to one (and did not change it in the first then-block).

**D. What is `intCounter` good for?**

- You initialize it to 0.
- You increment it if the username equals
  usercheck.
- The while loop loops as long as username is not equal to
  usercheck and intCounter equals 0.

Thus, both condition will be fullfilled if `username` equals `usercheck`.

You could eliminate `intCounter`.

This is a good example for a bad variable name. "`intCounter`" neither guarantees that it is an `int`, nor that it contains a count of anything. You will find that if you try to create useful names, you'll tend to create useful code. In your example, you created a useless name, and useless code that manipulates the value behind the name, but really don't accomplish anything.

**E. What are you trying to accomplish?**
Except for the headline of the question, there is no specification of the requirements your code tries to cover. Better specify what you want to do, then present the code, and specify your problem. Don´t just throw some general keywords at us, followed by code. Please ;)

Comment: could you explain the code in noob-friendly language? i mean, i dont get the !infile.eof () part. Could you break it down?

Comment: Well I suggest to use the NOT operator (! in Java) instead of comparing the infile method´s return false to false. I consider this more readable.